# Calculating TPR, FPR by hand vs scikit-learn via ROC curve

Tags: python, scikit-learn

So, giving the scikit-learn function *roc_curve* two arrays of True and False values

```
fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(self.real_values_discrete, self.predictions_discrete)
```

I receive values like this:

```
>>> [0.         0.63888889 1.        ]
>>> [0.         0.54330709 1.        ]
>>> [2 1 0]
```

Though, calculating FPR and TPR by hand, using the formulas, and scikit-learn function *confusion_matrix*:

```
confusion_matrix = confusion_matrix(self.real_values_discrete, self.predictions_discrete)
print(confusion_matrix)
_tp = confusion_matrix[0, 0]
_fn = confusion_matrix[0, 1]
_fp = confusion_matrix[1, 0]
_tn = confusion_matrix[1, 1]
_tpr = _tp / (_tp + _fn)
_fpr = _fp / (_tn + _fp)
print(_fpr)
print(_tpr)
```

I get these two values

```
>>> 0.4566929133858268
>>> 0.3611111111111111
```

I don't understand why values calculated by hand, and the middle values from the arrays above differ.

Are these values meant to be different or I don't understand something/have an error somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

`roc_curve()` operates on scores (e.g. the result of `predict_proba()`), not predictions. Used properly, it should return the TPR and FPR values for every possible classification threshold (unique score count + 1 points).

`confusion_matrix()` operates on predictions, thus assuming a default threshold of 0.5.